# How to include a jar URI in a submit job function on Dataproc

Tags: google-cloud-platform, pyspark, google-cloud-dataproc, jupyterhub

I am trying to run a PySpark job via jupyter and I need to create a function to run the job. I need to pass a jar file and I am trying to figure out how to do that. 
I did find some documentation on it: https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.dataproc.v1#google.cloud.dataproc.v1.SubmitJobRequest

https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/reference/rest/v1beta2/HadoopJob

But I am not able to figure out exactly how to add the URI to the function. My function currently looks something like this:

```
from google.cloud import dataproc_v1

def submit_pyspark_job(dataproc_cluster_client, project, region, cluster_name, bucket_name,
                       filename):
    """Submit the Pyspark job to the cluster (assumes `filename` was uploaded
    to `bucket_name."""
    job_details = {
        'placement': {
            'cluster_name': cluster_name
        },
        'pyspark_job': {
            'jar_file_uris':'gs://hadoop-lib/bigquery/bigquery-connector-hadoop2-latest.jar', #PROBLEM HERE!
            'main_python_file_uri': 'gs://{}/{}'.format(bucket_name, filename)
        }
    }

    result = dataproc_cluster_client.submit_job(
        project_id=project, region=region, job=job_details)
    job_id = result.reference.job_id
    print('Submitted job ID {}.'.format(job_id))
    return job_id
```

The problem is with the jar_file_uris part of the job details argument. Currently, I am getting an error.

Answer (score 2):

So I figured out the fix. The function should instead be declared as:

```
def submit_pyspark_job(dataproc_cluster_client, project, region, cluster_name, bucket_name,
                       filename):
    """Submit the Pyspark job to the cluster (assumes `filename` was uploaded
    to `bucket_name."""
    job_details = {
        'placement': {
            'cluster_name': cluster_name
        },
        'pyspark_job': {
            'main_python_file_uri': 'gs://{}/{}'.format(bucket_name, filename),
            'jar_file_uris':['gs://hadoop-lib/bigquery/bigquery-connector-hadoop2-latest.jar']
        }
    }

    result = dataproc_cluster_client.submit_job(
        project_id=project, region=region, job=job_details)
    job_id = result.reference.job_id
    print('Submitted job ID {}.'.format(job_id))
    return job_id
```

The URI needs to be passed as an array rather than a string. This fixes the issue.